# Как отправить сообщение при твоём пинге в discord?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Понимаю что self bot это плохо и нарушает ToS, но кого это волнует, верно? В любом случае мой друг не умеет пользовать ни стаком, ни гуглом да и самому узнать было бы интересно.

Сама проблема: На сервере пингуют меня и мне нужно чтобы при таком пинге бот отвечал на такое сообщение по типу "Перестань меня пинговать!"
Как пример на сервере пишут:

> Hello, @ThIsIsTails!

И в след бот пишет:

> Do not ping me! okay?

Кода нету поэтому такой вопрос и задал, а доки discord.py не дают по этому поводу ничего. Как вариант можно проверить сообщение на `<@UserID>`, но не факт что python вернёт положительный результат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он вернет положительный результат в любом случае(я проверял больша ста раз).

Вот проверка на наличие пинга:

```py
if '@USER' in message.content:
    await message.channel.send('Don"t ping me! okay?')
```

Если вы не понимаете, как это приклеить добавьте эту функцию -

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if '@USER' in message.content:
    await message.channel.send('Don"t ping me! okay?')
```

Comment: Мой Ответ помог?

Comment: Да, но нужно @user заменить на <@userID>